# Why does Open XML API Import Text Formatted Column Cell Rows Differently For Every Row

Tags: openxml

I am working on an ingestion feature that will take a strongly formatted `.xlsx` file and import the records to a temp storage table and then process the rows to create db records.

One of the columns is strictly formatted as "Text" but it seems like the Open XML API handles the columns cells differently on a row-by-row basis.  Some of the values while appearing to be numeric values are truly not (which is why we format the column as Text) -

some examples are `"211377", "211727.01", "209395.388", "209395.435"`

what these values represent is not important but what happens is that some values (using the Open XML API v2.5 library) will be read in properly as text whether retrieved from the Shared Strings collection or simply from InnerXML property while others get sucked in as numbers with what appears to be appended rounding or precision.

For example the `"211377", "211727.01" and "209395.435"` all come in exactly as they are in the spreadsheet but the `"209395.388"` value is being pulled in as `"209395.38800000001"` (there are others that this happens to as well).

There seems to be no rhyme or reason to which values get messed up and which ones which import fine.  What is really frustrating is that if I use the native Import feature in SQL Server Management Studio and ingest the same spreadsheet to a temp table this does not happen - so how is that the SSMS import can handle these values as purely text for all rows but the Open XML API cannot.

Comment: I guess what you are seeing is simply a float mis-precission you can not avoid. You might need to round float values to a certain amount of significant digits. Even better (if needed) is to use pure integers and divide them by 10**n where needed.

Comment: This will not work - these are not meant to be numeric values and that is why I explicitly set the column format to be text.  What is the point of having that feature in Excel if it not going to be applied to each and every row.  Yes they look like numeric values but they are not numeric values - they represent something completely different in the context of our company and thus the reason why I set the column format on the Excel file to Text (and which Excel says it will do even for "numbers" stored in rows in the column) but then it does not truly honor it or at least the XML API does not.

Comment: I have been using Excel over many years. Though I think it's the only really useful tool Mickeysoft ever has bought it still has flaws. And one ever has been the file import. The CSV was broken for ever and has never been fixed. So why expect other import formats to be clean? The only way is to find the right trick (or someone who knows the right trick). All derivates seem to have inherited the same flaws in the import.

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but just curious, have you tried to save the values with an apostrophe, instead of double quotes? Like '209395.388 instead of "209395.388"

Answer (score 0):

To begin the answer you main problem seems to be values,

> "209395.388" value is being pulled in as "209395.38800000001"

Yes in .xlsx file value is stored as `209395.38800000001` instead of  `209395.388`. And it's the correct format to store floating point numbers; nothing wrong in it. You van simply confirm it by following code snippet

```
string val = "209395.38800000001"; // <= What we extract from Open Xml

Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(val)); // < = Simply pass it to double and print
```

The output is :

```
209395.388   // <= yes the expected value
```

So there's nothing wrong in the value you extract from .xlsx using Open Xml SDK.

Now to cells, yes cell can have verity of formats. Numbers, text, boleans or shared string text. And you can `styles` to a cell which would format your string to a desired output in Excel. (Ex - Date Time format, Forced strings etc.). And this the way Excel handle the vast verity of data. It need this kind of formatting and .xlsx file format had to be little complex to support all.

My advice is to use a proper parse method set at extracted values to identify what format it represent (For example to determine whether its a number or a text) and apply what type of `parse`.

ex : -

```
string val = "209395.38800000001";

Console.WriteLine(float.Parse(val)); // <= Float parse will be deduce a different value ; 209395.4
```

Update :

Here's how value is saved in internal XML

[image]

Try for yourself ;

```
Make an .xlsx file with value 209395.388 -> Change extention to .zip -> Unzip it -> goto worksheet folder -> open Sheet1
```

You will notice that value is stored as 209395.38800000001 as scene in attached image.. So nothing wrong on API for extracting stored number. It's your duty to decide what format to apply.

But if you make the whole column Text **before** adding data, you will see that .xlsx hold data as it is; simply said as string.

Comment: What is the point of being able to explicitly set a column format to be "Text" if the Excel or the XML API is not going to honor it.  I set the column format to be "Text" therefore I expect every single value whether it could be construed as numeric value or not to be treated as text - period.  Seems pointless for Microsoft to provide that feature if it is not truly going to work.

Comment: @jensenma1 Then you shall make a news format to match your requirement. PERIOD

Comment: the values in the spreadsheet are not stored like "209395.38800000001" - if you open the file in Excel it will show you "209395.388" in the cell, even if you change the cell format to Number and give it 10 decimal places it will not show as "209395.38800000001" - it still only shows the 3 trailing digits.  So my question is why, when the entire column is set to "Text" format does the value come in like a floating point number when Excel is not showing it as such - my only finger to point is at the OpenXML API because that is the point at which the value gets messed up.

Comment: @jensenma1 You have a wrong interpretation here :) that's the problem. Value 209395.388 in .xlsx file is stored as 209395.38800000001 .. OpenXMl API is NOT Excel, it purely extract what stored inside XML files.. Look at the updated answer.. Mark the answer as correct if helps/solves your question.

Comment: I get what you are saying and I agree with you but why should I have to do it before I paste data - which in fact the template file we provide to our users is setup as - and which was used by the user to paste the data into.  Yet it seems Excel did not honor the fact that the column was already formatted as TEXT and did mess up the values.  But this does not happen to all rows that have values that are just like "209395.388" - there are 100's of other rows with the exact same format that do not get dorked up - all I'm asking is for consistent behavior.

Comment: that's the way Excel behaves.. And that's how Excel (and others) handle floating point precision.. If you can't accept the behavior best option is to handle it in another format/way.

Comment: So I guess my question is - what is Excel doing to the value to show it as 209395.388 even if behind the scenes it is stored as 209395.38800000001 (or some such value).   Whatever Excel is doing to the displayed value to show it as I expect it to be shown is what I expect the Open XML API to do (i.e. Microsoft should share what it is doing so Open XML has the same capability since they are on this big open-source kick now).

Comment: No Open XML does the job of either creating Open XML files or Read from Open XML files.. It merely manipulate values and does not consider how they will be represented in Excel.. That's the answer for your question :) ..